# IDEA 2023.1 - cannot disable @NotNull generation?

Tags: intellij-idea

When using "extract method" refactoring, IDEA always generates a `@NotNull` annotation - I don't want it do that.

How do I configure IDEA 2023.1 to not generate this (or any other not-null) annotation?

Note that old versions of IDEA were able to disable this annotation - there are questions related to that, but the answers are no longer relevant.

The "Nullable/NotNull configuration does not allow removal of annotations, nor does it allow selection any kind of "none" option:
[image]

The "Extract method" intention is no longer configurable:
[image]

Comment: There is "Annotate" or "Generate Annotation" option in refactoring dialog.

Answer (score 0):

There should be an "annotate" option when you press a gear icon upon invoking the refactoring:

[image]

Note that this option should appear only when possible, meaning any sufficient library should be present in the project and set in the Nullability settings for generation.

But it seems to be not present at least in [one case](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-318385).
You can attach your sample project in the comments of this bug if it doesn't cover your case.